# Calculating the distance between two latitude and longitude Geocordinate in a R dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the distance between two latitude and longitude locations in a dataframe.

```
df <- tibble("lat1"=c(0,1,2),"lon1"=c(0,1,2),"lat2"=c(90,91,92),"lon2"=c(90,91,92))

df %>% 
dplyr::mutate(distance_trip=mapply(FUN = distHaversine,c(lat1, lon1),c(lat2, lon2)))
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
*Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `distance_trip`.
ℹ `distance_trip = mapply(FUN = distHaversine, c(lat1, lon1), c(lat2, lon2))`.
x Wrong length for a vector, should be 2
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.*
```

Not sure why I am unable to apply the function to the data frame.

Comment: And what a nice, reproducible, and clear first question! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things going on here:

1. `geosphere::distHaversine` is vectorized, (matricized?), so that if we give it `matrix` input, we don't need to use `mapply` to do it one-row-at-a-time. This will be much faster.
2. `c()` just sticks things together. `c(lat1, lon1)` will be `0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2`, one after the other. We need `cbind` to make a matrix. (I see what you were going for with `mapply`, but the long `c(lat1, lon1)` vector is what you're passing **in** to `mapply`, instead you'd need to pass `lat1` and `lon1` in separately and `c()` the individual items inside the `FUN`... but the `matrix` approach will be better.)
3. Despite the colloquial usage of "lat, lon", almost all functions expect "lon, lat", as longitude is more like "x" and latitude is more like "y" and the `(x, y)` paradigm holds.
4. The maximum latitude is 90, but your `lat2` has values 91 and 92, which will cause an error if not addressed.

Fixing all of these, we can use:

```
df <- tibble(
  "lat1"=c(0,1,2),
  "lon1"=c(0,1,2),
  "lat2"=4:6,  ## valid latitudes
  "lon2"=c(90,91,92)
)

library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)

df %>% 
  mutate(distance_trip = geosphere::distHaversine(
    cbind(lon1, lat1), cbind(lon2, lat2)
  ))
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#    lat1  lon1  lat2  lon2 distance_trip
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1     0     0     4    90     10018754.
# 2     1     1     5    91     10009053.
# 3     2     2     6    92      9995487.
```

This is how to make it work with `mapply`--it's a bit more awkward to write and will be slower too :(

```
df %>% 
  mutate(distance_trip = mapply(
    FUN = function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      distHaversine(c(x1, y1), c(x2, y2))
    },
    x1 = lon1, y1 = lat1, x2 = lon2, y2 = lat2
  ))
## same result as above
```